# Show HTML field from the database in ASP.NET MVC3 view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I feel like this should be easy, but it seems to be stumping me.

I have a database field that contains HTML.  For instance, the field may contain the following:

```
<html>
 <p>This is HTML from the database.</p>
</html>
```

Now, all I want to do is render this HTML onto the page.  Instead it is displaying the actual HTML markup.

I am sure this is simple, but I have been searching around for a while and have yet to find a solution.

Thanks in advance for any help!  Be easy on me:)

Comment: How do you display it on the page?

Comment: Real curious as to why I got a downvote weeks after I accepted my answer.  Love StackOverflow, but some of the people in the community are ODD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Decoded

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.YourHtmlContent));
```

Unenconded

```
@Html.Raw(Model.YourHtmlContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using razor views use

```
@Html.Raw(model.foo)
```